# how to clear old path for flutter

Tags: flutter

I was trying to install flutter in MAC, mistakenly I run export path command many times, now when I echo $PATH it shows all paths which I took mistakenly,

question is, can I clear it or there is no issue of it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x

Comment: closing the shell and reopening it might do (depending on what you did exactly).

Comment: it a long answer, can you please answer me with word, will all old path values make an issue or not? please Dear

Comment: it does not matter, what old path is

Answer (score 0):

The **flutter** changes your $PATH variable for running by command line. This $PATH variable can sets in a some files. Please, look these file contents for flutter path.

Try to open these files (if exists)

`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` (It changes by your terminal shell)

If you find a line like this, you can remove or change the path of flutter.

`export PATH="~/flutter/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: can you please answer me with one word, will all old path values make an issue or not? please Dear

Comment: If the old path value is flutter path, yes. Please try to run this command and write output me. ‘echo $PATH’

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: I have installed flutter in a desktop folder called flu  and I don't its name there in output